# Fineuploader plugin doesn't work - what am I missing?

Tags: jquery, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I'm trying to use Fineuploader S3 to upload straight to Amazon from the client. I have the following file referenced:

**s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.4.0.min.js**

And I'm using the default template:

```
<div id="fineUploader"></div>

    <script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
        <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader">
            <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
                <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
            </div>
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                <div>Browse...</div>
            </div>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
                <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
                <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
            </span>
            <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list">
                <li>
                    <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                        <div class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                    <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon"></span>
                    <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                    <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                    <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                    <a class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                    <a class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry" href="#">Retry</a>
                    <a class="qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete" href="#">Delete</a>
                    <span class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </script>
```

And initializing like this:

```
$('#fineUploader').fineUploaderS3({
            debug: true,
            autoUpload: true,
            request: {
                endpoint: "http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com",
                accessKey: "MY_AWS_PUBLIC_ACCESS_KEY"//,
                //params: { category: "foobar" }
            },
            signature: {
                endpoint: "/s3/signtureHandler"
            },
            uploadSuccess: {
                endpoint: "/s3/uploadSuccessful"
            }, // etc etc etc.
```

It seems that the script works, because I see a Browse button that lets me pick files with a file dialog. But as soon as I select a file and click 'Open', nothing happens. I thought it would try to start the upload, but it just closes the file dialog.

Am I missing something here? What do I need to do in order to upload the file(s)?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the output from the browser console:
**[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Parsing template

[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Template parsing complete

[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Rendering template in DOM

[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Template rendering complete

event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. (jquery-1.10.2.js:5388)**

Comment: Is this `MY_AWS_PUBLIC_ACCESS_KEY` what you literally have there? If so, you should replace this with your own AWS key.

Comment: No, I haven't actually configured the details yet. I just expected the plugin to do *something* after I pick a file.. (don't see anything in browser console). Do you think it will start uploading after I fix the endpoint configurations properly?

Comment: I can't tell if you have other obstacles in your code, but it's worth trying. Come back after you had configured everything and tell us what happened.

Comment: You are initializing the uploader once the DOM has finished loading, right?

Comment: Also, you are including the default CSS with Fine Uploader, right?

Comment: This is unlikely to be a CSS issue.  Please report any error messages you see in your console after adjusting the default values per the documentation.

Comment: Correct, I'm initializing on DOM ready event. It seems to initialize properly because it turns the <div> into a file input with file select dialog. But when I select a file and click Open, nothing happens in the Console nor the Network activity. I believe it's supposed to fire a POST request to my server to get the signed policy, but it doesn't do that. Nothing happens, with no errors or activity anywhere. (I configured everything properly with my credentials). Any other ideas?

Comment: Please include any error messages you see in your browser's dev tools console.  Based on your comment, I'm confident that there will be error messages.

Comment: I kept an eye on the console, and nothing shows up. I tried it in both Chrome and IE dev tools.

Comment: Odd.  Add a `debug: true` to the options, and paste the exact contents of the console in Chrome after you have reproduced.

Comment: Ok, I just added the console contents as an EDIT to the original question at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I seem to have figured it out. It appears that somehow the events from FineUploader didn't bubble up through my DOM. This is because I had the upload button inside of a Knockout JS 'with' binding, which I guess was swapping out DOM elements behind the scenes. Getting rid of the 'with' binding solved the issue.

Thank you all so much for helping! Much appreciated!

Comment: Which events are you referring to?

Comment: I guess the events that fire when you click Open in the file dialog? As soon as I moved the fineuploader div & template to the top of the page instead of in my (initially hidden) Bootstrap modal, it started working. Now I just need to figure out why that happened, because obviously something in my DOM got in the way of the plugin.